# How do I separate the first argument from that of getopts?

Tags: bash, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments, getopts

```
#!/bin/bash

priority=false
it=0
dir=/

while getopts  "p:i" option
do
  case $option in
         i) it=$OPTARG;;
         p) priority=true;;
   esac
done

if [[ ${@:$OPTIND} != "" ]]
then
    dir=${@:$OPTIND}
fi
echo $priority $it $dir
```

If I execute it I get `2 testDir` for `$dir` and `0` for `$it`, instead of just `testDir` for `$dir` and `2` for `$it`. How can I get the expected behavior?

```
./test.sh -pi 2 testDir
true 0 2 testDir
```

Comment: If you use -p 2 -i testDir do you get the behavior you want?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash

Comment: Run `bash -x ./test.sh` to see what your script is doing. The `if` block looks really weird: it means if there is a non-empty non-option argument, then set `dir` to the result of performing pathname expansion and word splitting on the non-option arguments and concatenating them with spaces. (Complicated, eh?) I suspect you meant `if [[ ${!OPTIND} != "" ]]; then dir=${!OPTIND}; fi`. The usual method is even simpler: run `shift $OPTIND` after parsing the option, so that the non-option arguments are `$1`, `$2` and so on, thus `if [[ -n $1 ]]; then dir=$1; fi`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have the optstring parameter to `getopts` wrong. You have `p:i`, while what you want is `pi:`, so that the -i switch takes the argument.

Answer (score 2):

I would write this:

```
#!/bin/bash

priority=false
it=0

while getopts ":hpi:" opt; do
    case "$opt" in
        h) echo "usage: $0 ...."; exit 0 ;;
        p) priority=true ;;
        i) it="$OPTARG" ;;
        *) echo "error: invalid option -$OPTARG"; exit 1 ;;
    esac
done

shift $(( OPTIND - 1 ))

dir="${1:-/}"

echo "priority=$priority"
echo "it=$it"
echo "dir=$dir"
```